# Remote ubuntu (Mint) becomes unreachable after running upgrade to oneiric

Tags: ssh, mint

Got this message when I logged in and decided to upgrade. I am a noob. So anyways, I ran the command and next thing I know, I can no longer log into it after the reboot. What the heck happened?

I get ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxxx port 22: Network is unreachable

> New release 'oneiric' available. Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade
>   to it.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was just Ubuntu and not Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remote ubuntu (Mint) becomes unreachable

Linux Mint is actually a derivative of Ubuntu; I don't think [it allows you to do a `do-release-upgrade` the way Ubuntu does](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2). So it's quite possible the upgrade to "Ubuntu" from "Mint" messed something up which.... (see below)

> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxxx port 22: Network is unreachable

...left the remote computer unable to connect to the internet (which is exactly what this error means). Since it's not connected, the only way to troubleshoot this is if you (or someone else) can somehow access the Mint computer locally. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Yes, I have the machine now. Lot of trouble getting hold of it. I should just have run ubuntu and forget Mint. Too much hassle.

Comment: Actually, if I remember correctly.. I think I did have Ubuntu and not Linux Mint...

Comment: Well, did you get it working now?

Comment: I am just going to reformat everything. Don't want to mess with it anymore. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting was not necessary.  The only fix was to contact your VPS support crew and have them rebuild GRUB for you, a simple task but requires on-site assistance.